# The meaning of "aggressive"

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I am writing a story in which a man has ambivalent feelings about a woman.  He often goes out of his way to disrespect and **disparage** her.  My question is whether this behavior counts as **aggressive**.

I know that *disparage* means to treat as unworthy, literally from its origins, not (*dis*) + equal (*par*), but dictionaries list *denigrate* as a synonym.  Denigrate means to use words to attack, and an attack is the key idea behind aggression.

So does *aggressive* necessarily imply a physical attack, and if not, does that make it redundant when used with *disparage*?

Comment: My personal answer is yes, but the issue is very opinion-based

Comment: Please look up a good dictionary and let's see what you find.

Comment: As it stands, the  Q may risk being closed as GR/POB. @Josh61 POBs are OT.

Comment: @Kris - that is what I said in my comment.

Comment: There are different kinds of disrespect and disparaging. If I completely blank someone, that's unlikely to be aggressive. If I calmly call a certain politician a "hairpiece-wearer with ... um ... interesting if not reactionary views," that's unlikely to be aggressive. *Aggressive* is likely to be defined in a dictionary: please show your research. Also check what's actually on-topic, because a question like this needs to be carefully worded not to fall into the opinion-based category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They often go together.  Aggression is the propensity for hostility, and if you require physical action for your aggression, the disparagement may be separate entirely.  Consider the Monty Python [taunt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAy4zULKFDU) from *The Holy Grail*.

> Your mother was a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries.

The taunter was in a *defensive* position, behind a castle's parapet.  There's also passive-aggression, in which the disparagement is indirect and may be concealed behind a facade of concern:

> Well, you missed the mark as usual, but we still love you.

Note that in legal arenas, such niceties are not observed:  *aggression* requires physical force or the threat of physical force.  This is the definition for countries under the Rome Statute that set up the International Criminal Court, and it's a requirement under state laws in the US, for example Florida's infamous stand-your-ground law, 776.041.  Simple disparagement wouldn't be enough to trigger legal sanctions.

Comment: An experienced user like yourself should know not to answer blatantly off topic questions like this.

Comment: @curiousdannii I upvoted this answer. Did I also do something wrong? The question might have some room for improvement, but I don't think the question is ***very off-topic*** because it is related with English Language and its Usage. Have you thought about guiding the OP to write a better/more on-topic question?

Comment: @curiousdannii This question is not off topic.  It's about the connotation of the word *aggression* and the kind of attack inherent in the meaning of the word.  The subtleties are illustrated in the locutions "naked aggression" and "passive aggression."

Comment: This question 'smells of' legal issues.

Comment: @Josh61 I must have read your mind.  I added the legal stuff before I read your comment.

Comment: @Rathony I don't know how I could possibly instruct the OP better than the sidebar: show your research.

Comment: @curiousdanii The question is about the meaning of an adjective. I would like to use the adjective for a specific case and I wanted to make sure that I could. I don't think the question is "blatantly off-topic".

Comment: @V Then you need to explain that context in the question! You also need to show the dictionaries you consulted.

Comment: @V.Lydia Of course it isn't blatantly off-topic. It isn't off-topic at all, and is, in fact, an interesting question of where we drawn the semantic line between criticism and attack. But you've run into an ELU cultural issue about the phrasing of your question:  could somebody do something?  People can do all sorts of things, so to answer your question literally is to speculate on what people might do, which isn't a matter of English usage.  Would you like me to help recast your question?  You may reject the edits if they're inapt. It would be good to know the "specific case" you had in mind.

Comment: @deadrat I would like you to help me recast my question. I'm writing an essay, in which I should analyse a character. He has mixed feelings towards a woman and often disrespects and insults her. I was wondering if it would be right to claim that he is rather aggressive.